# About length of an element $g\in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finitely-generated

Let $G=\langle S\rangle$ be a finitely generated group and $A\subseteq G$ be given. For $g\in G$ we denote by $l_S(g)$ length of $g$ with respect $S$.

In my research, for every $g\in G$ I need to find $h\in G$ with minimal length such that $hg\in A$.

> Q. Let $s\in S$ be given and for $g\in G$ choose $h\in G$ with minimal length such that $hg\in A$. If $h$ does not start with $s$, what can say about $sg\in G$?
>   i.e. Can I say $h'= hs^{-1}$ has minimal length such that $h'sg\in A$?

Comment: You first write "if $h$ does not start with $s$", and later you consider $hs^{-1}$. Did you mean to instead write "if $h$ does not end with $s$"? In order to guarantee that the word $hs^{-1}$ is reduced?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $G=A$, then for any $g\in G$ we get $h=e$, so $h$ does not start or end with $s$, but of course $sg$ is already in $A$ so we may choose $h'=e$ and not $s\cdot h =s$ which has longer length (1 and not 0).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in my research, $A\neq G$. What can say in this state?

Comment: I didn't really use the fact that $G=A$, just there exist an element in $g \in A$ and $s\in S$ such that $sg\in A$.